# Returning a random <td> value with a click with console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have been searching to see how you can return a value from a table in console.log.  For example:

If I have an array, I can generate a random value back from the array like this:

```
var questionsarray = ["index 0, how to use javascript console to update variable?"];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}

function quizloops() {
return(questionsarray[getRandomInt(0,2)]) }
```

When I am in Javascript console, I use quizloops(), and I get a random index from the array.

How can I generate the same but from a table?
It'll be nice if there is a button that I can use that will generate a value with console.log.

```
<table id="tbl1">
    <tr>
        <td id="1>Henk</td>
        <td class="day">tuesday</td>
        <td>sample1</td>
        <td>sample2</td>
        <td>sample3</td>
        <td>sample4</td>
        <td></td>
        <td id="number_2">667</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Get all `td` from the table. Since you are using jquery `$("#tbl1").children('tbody').children('tr').children('td')` will be a jquery object.

`tds.length` will give the total number of `td`. Pass this value to `getRandomInt`. Assuming your table can have 0 `td` hence minimum value is 0.

Once the random number is generated use the same jquery object to retrieve the text using `text()` method.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


$('#gen').on('click', function() {
  var tds = $("#tbl1").children('tbody').children('tr').children('td')
  var randomValue = getRandomInt(0, tds.length)
  console.log($(tds[randomValue]).text())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">Henk</td>
    <td class="day">tuesday</td>
    <td>sample1</td>
    <td>sample2</td>
    <td>sample3</td>
    <td>sample4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td id="number_2">667</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id='gen'>Generate</button>
```